# How can I make curved shaped panels and buttons in C# WPF?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create non-rectangular buttons and panels in C# Windows application without any sharp edges ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do just about anything design-wise if you can use WPF.  For example: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200706000504/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/cskardon/archive/2008/06/20/roundedbutton-button-style-wpf.aspx).

**EDIT:**

OK, no WPF.  How about this then:

- [Creating Gel Buttons with Windows Forms : Part 1](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/bg-p/Windows-Blog-Archive)
- [Creating Gel Buttons with Windows Forms : Part 2](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/bg-p/Windows-Blog-Archive)
- [Creating Gel Buttons with Windows Forms : Part 3](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/bg-p/Windows-Blog-Archive)

A pure Windows Forms approach.

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw, im not using wpf

Comment: The below website is some what near to my req., but i need the curved corners instead of oval shapes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw, This is wat i was looking for. Now i created a class file. How can i use that for my control ?

Comment: GelButton derives from Button so wherever you would have used Button but now want one with rounded corners, use GelButton instead.

Comment: @Daniel: Hope you didn't mind, but i added also the links to the on going parts of the series. Especially the last part should hold anything the OP needs.

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw, So how can i create the button click event for the button ? Now i see the auto generated code for buttons..should i replace that with GelButtons ?

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw, I tried to do :

GelButton Gbtn = new GelButton();
Gbtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(Gbtn_Click); 

Still i could not see the button. where am i going wrong ?

Comment: @srk: you'll need to add the button to the form's controls collection, etc.  Do you normally use drag-and-drop form creation?  If so, you can add the GelButton to the toolbox and just use it like an ordinary button.

Answer (score 0):

Customising the .NET Panel control:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/custompanel.aspx?msg=1042196

BorderWidth - Controls the width of the border.

BorderColor - The color of the border.

Curvature - The radius of the curve used to draw the corners of the panel.

CurveMode - The style of the curves to be drawn on the control.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, you can set the specify the curvature of a border with the `CornerRadius` attribute.

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8">
   <Grid/>
</Border>
```